# How to close SqlConnection automatically after SqlMapper GridReader in 3rd Library

Tags: dapper

Here is  code snippet from my own helper ,But it has some faults.

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Execute a command that returns multiple result sets, and access each in turn
  /// </summary>
  public static  SqlMapper.GridReader QueryMultiple(string sql, dynamic param = null, string connectionName = null)
  {

      using (SqlConnection connection = GetOpenConnection(connectionName))

      { return connection.QueryMultiple(sql, param);}

  }
```

QueryMultiple is called and closed manually by external program. Shortly after that, SqlConnection should be closed automatically , how to wrap up my helper? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, one option here might be: don't give it an open connection. This isn't deployed to nuget yet, but if you pull the version from github it actually now takes a lot more control over the connection if it needs to. All of the main methods (`Query[<T>]`, `QueryMultiple`, `Execute`) now work fine with closed connections, closing it again when it can. So if instead you had:

```
return GetClosedConnection(connectionName).QueryMultiple(sql, param);
```

then it will close automatically when the `GridReader` reaches the end of the data. Note that I've re-structured it to ensure we don't `Dispose()` the connection when leaving the method.

Comment: when i do as what you have told me, the error is" connection has been closed when grid reader "

Comment: @Kevin are you using the current source? Or the dll from nuget?

Comment: sorry for my carelessness, After I pull the newest dapper source code from github,It works well . Thanks a lot, Marc Gravell. I will continue using this great tool.